# VisualStudio 2019: Switch app from Console to Windows, get tons of linker errors

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, linker-errors

I have an OpenGL app I've just ported to Windows, and it works fine as a Console app. However, for the Release build, I'd like to avoid having that console terminal window pop up. My understanding is that all I have to do is go into Properties > Linker > System > SubSystem and switch it from Console to Windows. I also changed the entry point to main so that I don't have to do a bunch of unnecessary #ifdefs. Unfortunately, I now get a ton of linker errors. I've tried googling them, but I'm getting nowhere. I found something about missing dependencies on a "CRT," but it's already linking against MSVCRT.lib. Perhaps someone can help me figure out what to do.

```
1>blocklibrary.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>msvcprt.lib(filesystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>MSVCRT.lib(gshandlereh4.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>blocklibrary.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>MSVCRT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_destroy
1>blocklibrary.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_copy
1>MSVCRT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_exception_copy
1>blocklibrary.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_terminate
1>msvcprt.lib(filesystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __std_terminate
1>blocklibrary.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn
1>blocktype.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _purecall
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fputc
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fflush
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fclose
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fgetc
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__unlock_file
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__lock_file
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fwrite
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fgetpos
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_setvbuf
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ungetc
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fsetpos
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fread
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fseeki64
1>chunk.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__get_stream_buffer_pointers
1>datacontainer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___acrt_iob_func
1>datacontainer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vfprintf
1>facing.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_tolower
1>facing.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_atoi
1>facing.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_isdigit
1>filelocator.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strcat_s
1>geometry.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_lrint
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncmp
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncmp
1>glfw3.lib(context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncmp
1>glfw3.lib(egl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncmp
1>glfw3.lib(osmesa_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>msvcprt.lib(filesystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(vulkan.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(egl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_free
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strstr
1>glfw3.lib(context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strstr
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strstr
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsscanf
1>glfw3.lib(context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsscanf
1>glad.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_malloc
1>msvcprt.lib(filesystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_malloc
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_exit
1>glfw3.lib(osmesa_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(vulkan.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(egl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_calloc
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsprintf_s
1>mesh_parser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_atof
1>mesh_parser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_isspace
1>render.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__beginthreadex
1>render.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_terminate
1>msvcprt.lib(filesystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_terminate
1>stb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ftell
1>stb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ferror
1>stb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_realloc
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_realloc
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_realloc
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_realloc
1>stb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fseek
1>stb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_fopen_s
1>stb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strtol
1>stb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ldexp
1>stb.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_feof
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strcspn
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncpy
1>glfw3.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncpy
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strncpy
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strspn
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_strtoul
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(input.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_qsort
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_qsort
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memmove
1>glfw3.lib(monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol powf
1>glfw3.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___stdio_common_vsprintf
1>glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strcmp
1>glfw3.lib(vulkan.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol strcmp
1>msvcprt.lib(filesystem.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____lc_codepage_func
1>MSVCRT.lib(new_scalar.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _callnewh
1>MSVCRT.lib(new_scalar.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol malloc
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __vcrt_initialize
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __vcrt_uninitialize
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __vcrt_uninitialize_critical
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __vcrt_thread_attach
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __vcrt_thread_detach
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _seh_filter_dll
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _is_c_termination_complete
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _configure_narrow_argv
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _initialize_narrow_environment
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _initialize_onexit_table
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _register_onexit_function
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _execute_onexit_table
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _crt_atexit
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _crt_at_quick_exit
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __acrt_initialize
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __acrt_uninitialize
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __acrt_uninitialize_critical
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __acrt_thread_attach
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __acrt_thread_detach
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cexit
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>MSVCRT.lib(ehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>MSVCRT.lib(ehvecctr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler
1>MSVCRT.lib(ehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol terminate
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol terminate
1>MSVCRT.lib(ehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __current_exception
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __current_exception
1>MSVCRT.lib(ehvecdtr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __current_exception_context
1>MSVCRT.lib(utility_desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __current_exception_context
1>MSVCRT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CxxThrowException
1>MSVCRT.lib(delete_scalar.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol free
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a Windows project from scratch? I've no idea if all you need to do is switch from console to windows (although your experience seems to suggest that's not true) but if you create the project from scratch you can be sure to have all the right settings.

Comment: I thought about that. The problem is that I want the Debug to have a console but the Release to not. And I have already checked all the code into git and everything. If I great a new project, it'll be a huge hassle. Maybe what I can do is make an empty Windows project and then compare the config files to see what's different.

Comment: You could have a windows program which manually creates a console in Debug mode. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Well, I created a new project as a Windows app and dropped in all my source code and added the additional libraries (for openGL and stuff), and I get all the same linker errors.

Comment: Could you show you linker settings?

Comment: I figured it out. I tried setting the entrypoint to main, and that's what broke everything. I used the preprocessor to select between main() and WinMain based on _DEBUG, and now it works fine.

Comment: @TimothyMiller Glad you got it sorted. You could write your experience up as an answer for future reference. It's perfectly OK to answer your own questions.